# Keep html that is generated with javascript after laravel POST with old data

Tags: javascript, laravel

There are 2 fields that belong together price and size. Some products have more then 1 size, so the html offers a button to generate more fields. However if some validation fails the fields are gone and not populated anymore.

Here are the non generated html fields

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="price" class="form-label">Prijs* </label>
        <input type="text" 
               name="priceAndSize[price][0]"
               class="form-control @if($errors->has('priceAndSize.price.*')) border-danger @endif"
               id="price"
               value="{{ old('priceAndSize.price[0]') }}">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="stock" class="form-label">Inhoud in ml</label>
        <input type="text" 
               name="priceAndSize[size][0]" 
               class="form-control" 
               id="size"
               value="{{ old('priceAndSize.size[0]') }}">
    </div>
```

With a button to generate more fields

```
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-info mt-3 text-white" onclick="addInput()"
               value="Meerdere prijzen & inhoud"/>
```

the javascript to generate the fields:

```
counter = 1;

        function addInput() {
            // Input
            const newInputPrice = document.createElement('input');
            newInputPrice.id = 'price' + counter;
            newInputPrice.name = 'priceAndSize[price][' + counter + ']';
            newInputPrice.type = 'text';
            newInputPrice.className = 'form-control';

            const newInputSize = document.createElement('input');
            newInputSize.id = 'size' + counter;
            newInputSize.name = 'priceAndSize[size][' + counter + ']';
            newInputSize.type = 'text';
            newInputSize.className = 'form-control';


            // Label
            const labelPrice = document.createElement('label');
            labelPrice.htmlFor = 'price' + counter;
            labelPrice.innerHTML = 'Prijs* ';
            labelPrice.className = 'form-label';

            const labelSize = document.createElement('label');
            labelSize.htmlFor = 'size' + counter;
            labelSize.innerHTML = 'Inhoud* ';
            labelSize.className = 'form-label';

            // New boostrap div
            const newDivPrice = document.createElement('div');
            newDivPrice.className = 'col-md-6';

            const newDivSize = document.createElement('div');
            newDivSize.className = 'col-md-6';

            // Add label and input to div
            newDivPrice.appendChild(labelPrice);
            newDivPrice.appendChild(newInputPrice);

            newDivSize.appendChild(labelSize);
            newDivSize.appendChild(newInputSize);

            const currentDiv = document.getElementById("test");

            currentDiv.appendChild(newDivPrice);
            currentDiv.appendChild(newDivSize);

            counter++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your blade.

```
$priceAndSize = Request::old('priceAndSize');
@if(count($priceAndSize[price]) > 0)
  for (var i = 1; i <= {{count($priceAndSize[price])}}; i++) {
    addInput();
  }
@elseif(count($priceAndSize[size]) > 0)
  for (var i = 1; i <= {{count($priceAndSize[size])}}; i++) {
    addInput();
  }
@endif
```

Comment: This doesnt populate the fields with the old values?

Comment: I assume you are getting the values in the `$priceAndSize = Request::old('priceAndSize');` but you are not using it in your `addInput()` method which is just generating the markup, i did not see value attribute for the element `newInputPrice`